# Retrieving an ordered list from a map in java

Tags: java, collections, java-stream

let's assume I have a `HasMap<String, Student>`, where `Student` has a method `double getAverage()`, is there a clever way to retrieve a `List<String>` of keys from that `Map` ordered by decreasing average?

I was thinking about using streams for compactness, however this does not work:

```
List<String> ordered  = studentMap.entrySet().stream()
                .sorted((e1, e2) -> e2.getValue().getAverage().compareTo(e1.getValue().getAverage()))
                .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about which is the key and which is the value stored in the Hashmap?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your `.getAverage()` method indeed returns a `double`, there is no `.compareTo()` method.

Use this instead:

```
.sorted((e1, e2) -> Double.compare(e2.getValue().getAverage(), e1.getValue().getAverage()))
```

Answer (score 5):

You could use [`Comparator.comparingDouble`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#comparingDouble-java.util.function.ToDoubleFunction-) and [`Comparator.reversed()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#reversed--) for this purpose:

```
List<String> ordered  = studentMap.entrySet().stream()
                .sorted(Comparator.<Map.Entry<String, Student>>comparingDouble(e -> e.getValue().getAverage()).reversed())
                .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the limited type inference causes problems, when writing it this way. You may write it either as `Collections.reverseOrder(Comparator.comparingDouble(e -> e.getValue().getAverage()))` or simply `Comparator.comparingDouble(e -> -e.getValue().getAverage())`, unlike with `int` values, negation works when comparing `double`s (assuming that `NaN` isn’t relevant here).

Comment: @Holger Thanks for the note. IMHO it's easier to fix this by simply specifying the type parameter of `comparingDouble`. (fixed it in the post)

Answer (score 2):

If `getAverage()` returns a primitive (double), you can't use `compareTo`. Use `Double.compare` :

```
List<String> ordered  = studentMap.entrySet().stream()
                .sorted((e1, e2) -> Double.compare(e2.getValue().getAverage(),e1.getValue().getAverage()))
                .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```